# Sum and update group row using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a difficulty in summing and updating those row amount to one row of the same receiving column.

please can someone help me. here is the image.

[image].

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Are you trying to write a query to extract information, or do you really want to update the table you described?

Comment: I am just looking for a way to sum the amount of multiple reciever column ,update the amount  and remove (delete) the other columns

Comment: Other _columns_?  Do you mean other _rows_?  Please include your expected output from the above sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement, you want to delete all records from the original table, leaving only one per `receiver`.  And you want to update the `amount` for that remaining record to the sum of amounts for all records, for that `receiver`.  Rather than trying to deal with a complex update and delete operation, I might recommend that you just create a new table and insert the data you want into that:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (receiver varchar(11), amount int);
INSERT INTO new_table (receiver, amount)
SELECT receiver, SUM(amount)
FROM original_table
GROUP BY receiver
```

Then, you can drop the original table since you don't need/want it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT receiver, SUM(amount) as total
FROM table
GROUP BY receiver
```

This will add all `amount` with the same `receiver`

Comment: yes, I just want update the amount and live one row for each receiver

Comment: @ssshehu You're asking for a fairly complex operation, but are you sure you need it?  I think it would be easier to just write the data to a new table and delete the old one.